# Insert a range of numbers in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel which looks like this:

```
             A             B           C
Row 1:    2100-2200    2200-2300    2300-2400
```

I'm using a VLOOKUP formula. I want this formula to find a number e.g. 2152 in the table above.

Cell A1 is supposed to contain numbers from 2100 to 2200.

Is this possible to do in Excel?

Comment: You can create a **User Defined Function** to implement this.

Comment: What should 2200 return?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you want to return, this array formula will return the correct interval in A1:C1:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1;MATCH(1;(E1>=VALUE(LEFT($A$1:$C$1;4)))*(E1<=VALUE(RIGHT($A$1:$C$1;4)));0))
```

Numeric value your looking for in E1

Dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula...

Comment: This basically nice post is restricted to 4-digit numbers - c.f. my [more flexible approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855196/insert-a-range-of-numbers-in-one-cell/69486149#69486149) as of 2021-10-07 and using the `HLookUp` required by OP. - Furthermore  any semi-colon `;` *(used in some regional languages)* should be replaced by a comma `,` to make the Excel functions work in English versions. @CRondao

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing the ranges, you need to provide only the lower bound. I.e. try this data:

```
             A             B           C
Row 1:    2100          2200        2300
```

Because it is a horizontal setup, you need to use HLOOKUP (VLOOKUP will check the cells in the first column of a table, HLOOKUP the cells in the first row) - and you need to leave the fourth parameter of HLOOKUP/VLOOKUP blank (or set it to `TRUE` which is the same as leaving it blank). E.g. if you number `2152`is in cell A2, use this formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$C$1,1)
```

and you'll get `2100`.

If you want to have the full range returned, you should use the `MATCH` function instead:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$C$1))&"-"&INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$C$1)+1)
```

This will return `2100-2200`

Answer (score 0):

use lower range of your numbers

```
                     A        B          C      D
Lower range        2100     2200       2300     2400
Ranking              1        2         3        4
```

You want to find a number or ranking corresponding to say 2350

```
Formula:   = HLOOKUP(2350,range (range of your values),2,TRUE)
```

your range includes 2100 -2400 plus 1-4.

the value 2 in the formula indicates the row that you want result returned from - in this case you want ranking - where 2350 will return a 4; change this number to 1 to return exact value.

sample formula:

```
= HLOOKUP(O65,J74:N75,2,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP wants to apply `HLookUp` to numeric range strings (`"2100-2200"`, `"2200-2300"`, etc.), I suggest the following steps:

- reconstruct the range contents to their **starting values** *(`2100`,`2200`,`2300`) isolated via `Find` searching till the `-` delimiter)* by `VALUE(LEFT(A1:C1,FIND("-",A1:C1)-1))`
- define a *named* search cell `MySrch` (example value of `2151` due to OP) and apply `HLookUp` on the above values to get the lower boundary (here: `2100`),
- `Match` the found lower boundary (e.g. `2100`) plus character `"-"` and a `*` wild card to find the ordinal column position (here: 1st column),
- return the found range text (e.g. `2100-2200`) via `Index(A1:C1,1,{column number})` referring to row 1 and the column position as result:

```
   =INDEX(A1:C1,1,MATCH(HLOOKUP(MySrch,VALUE(LEFT(A1:C1,FIND("-",A1:C1)-1)),1)&"-*",A1:C1,0))
```

*Note* that it would be necessary to exclude search values outside the given range boundaries either by formula extension (e.g. `If(MySrch>...,"?",{above formula})` or to add a last range defining a maximum limit.

Answer (score 0):

if the number you search for is in E1 (aka e1 = 2152) then use 1 of 3:
the easiest and probably the best:

```
1) =HLOOKUP(E1 & "-" & E1,A1:C1,1,true)
```

or

```
2) =index(a1:c1,1, max(ARRAYFORMULA( if($E$1>VALUE(left(A1:C1,4)),column(A1:C1),0) )) )
```

or

```
3) =index(A1:c1,1, min(ARRAYFORMULA( if(VALUE(right(A1:C1,4))>=$E$1,column(A1:C1),99) )) )
```

this the range you want

to get the column remove the index(a1:c1,1, .... )  leaving the .... in 2) and 3) or use the fo;;owin gin 1)

```
=HLOOKUP(E1 & "-" & E1,{A1:C1 ; arrayformula(column(A1:C1))},2,true)
```

glad to help